# Найти программы с глобальными хуками

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, администрирование, поиск-программ

Как найти все программы, которые вмешиваются в работы мыши и/или клавиатуры? Имеется в виду не пассивное слежение, а именно потенциально активное вмешательство, которое способно поглощать нажатия, чтобы они не доходили до целевого приложения. Скорее всего, сюда относятся хуки клавиатуры и мыши.

Итак, как узнать, какие программы в данный момент обладают активными хуками клавиатуры и мыши?

Устраивают как готовые решения, так и код с использованием winapi или wmi. Или команды для wmic.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676830/11619532) с английского SO. Там и исходник, и готовая программа. Ради интереса запустил у себя, т.к. знал какие программы ставят хуки, программа показала и их и несколько других хуков, о которых не знал.

Comment: Хм.. Там несколько программ. А ещё, у меня x64.

Comment: Я попробовал на x64 вот эту http://www.airesoft.co.uk/files/MsgHookLister.zip. Там и x86, x64

Comment: Не работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bt5e.png. К тому же, а зачем ей драйвер?

Comment: Я запускал с параметром `\L`

Comment: Это вообще не то: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xLb0.png. К тому же, не похоже, чтобы даже оно работало.